# Argument matchers for type parameters when using Mockito

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, mockito-scala, argument-matching

I was trying to find out if I can use something like the `any` argument matcher for a method with type parameters:

```
when(store.getItems[Product](any[FilterParams]))
        .thenReturn(allProducts)
```

When running the code with the above snippet, I get this error:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded
```

I guessed this would be because I passed an exact type parameter `Product` to the `getItems` method.

This does work when I pass in an actual `FilterParams` object:

```
when(store.getItems[Product](FilterParams()))
        .thenReturn(allProducts)
```

Is there any argument matcher that I can use for the type parameter? Or is it counter-intuitive, because whenever we're calling a function with a type parameter, we *have* to pass the type parameter?

**Edit:**

`Product` here isn't Scala's built-in `Product` trait.

The function signature of the `getItems` method:

```
def getItems[T <: ItemType : universe.TypeTag](filterParams: FilterParams): List[T]
```

Comment: Can you please add the definition of `store.getItems`?

Comment: @TomerShetah I've added the signature of the function to the question. Function definition involves querying the database, so thought I'd just put the signature here. Thank you.